# Problems with Odoo v11 and PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo-11

I'm new working with Odoo and I'm trying to implement the virtual env but I can't implement it because I need install a package named "dateutil", the package is installed but still can't running. I've tried install with the manager package and it doesn't working. So this the output when I try to running the project:

```
/root/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/bin/python /home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/setup/odoo -c odoo-server.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/setup/odoo", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/odoo/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .convert import *
  File "/home/jose/Proyectos/odoo11/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 12, in <module>
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil
```

'

About the package manager, I've put this link in the "Manage Repositories" and it doesn't save it.

Also I've tried with these commands but I doesn't recognize it.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: I think you just select the wrong interpreter in pycharm.

Comment: Thx, I've solved this problem

Comment: Can you please add an answer to describe how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install -r src/odoo/requirements.txt

Comment: Your answer could be even more helpful if you explain what it does and why it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

odoo v11 running with >= python3.6

your enviroment is python 2.x "`/root/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/bin/python`"

let's check python version and install requirements.txt